# Unity - compressed .jpg and .png files get uncompressed when building apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my 2d game, I have about **20 background images**, that i've turned into **.jpg** files (Edit: and also compressed them). Their total size is around **9MB**, but for some reason, **when I build the apk, they get uncompressed** and they take up a lot more space. **How to prevent this?** Thank you!

Edit: new issue

> Some little triangles appear on my buttons, only in-game.

This is what I see in the scene (and should see in-game):
[image]

This is what I see in-game (circles added later):
[image]

**Why is this caused and how can i fix this problem?**

Thank you

Comment: Are your mip maps set to none?

What is the size of your background images (1080x1920?)

Comment: @ErikOverflow not sure how do i see that? The (compressed) resolution is around 1400*2300 in avarage. Before some were over 8k.

Comment: I likely have your answer. Give me a moment to write it out.

Comment: Can you expand on how you compressed them, and with which algorithm? Did you set the "Texture compression" Under Build Settings > Android to something like ETC2?

Comment: @Remy_rm I reduced them [here](https://resizeimage.net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphics are most performant when their pixel width/height are powers of 2. The performance is so significant that most engines (Unity included) will automatically scale all textures to a power of 2.

From Unity's [Importing Textures documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ImportingTextures.html)

> If the platform or GPU does not support NPOT Texture sizes, Unity scales and pads the Texture up to the next power of two size. This process uses more memory and makes loading slower (especially on older mobile devices). In general, you should only use NPOT sizes for GUI purposes.

For some platforms, the above rule results in a 2300x1400 texture scaling up to 4096x2048.

### For 2D sprites, Sprite Atlases can help you

[Sprite Atlas documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteAtlas.html)

> A Sprite Atlas is an Asset that consolidates several Textures into a single combined Texture.

You can create a Master sprite atlas, and set it to be included in your build. This packs all of your textures into a single Power-of-Two texture. Since Unity will use the Sprite Atlas in the build and not the individual textures, it won't upscale all of your original textures to a power of two. As a result, you will save a significant amount of space. Note: You will probably need to change your max texture size in your sprite atlas since you are using textures that are over 2048.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the right answer for me. By creating sprite atlas for all the textures of my game, the apk size is not 35MB! It's great! One more quick question: I saw that using crunch compression helps a lot to reduce the apk size. But does it affect the quality of the textures in game afterwards or no? Thank you very much!

Comment: There are 2 types of compression. Lossy and Lossless. Crunch compression is lossy, so that means that data is "lost" when compressed (so your quality might be slightly lower). You probably won't see much of a decrease in size, though. Also, did you mean "The apk size is now 35MB"? @enricortinovis

Comment: Yes! I managed to get it down to 32MB using sprite atlas for everything. I also realized that even by using crush compression set to 50% does not make a big difference (and i'm looking it on a 6.6 inch android phone). Thanks a lot for your help! I will assign the 50 reputation to this answer! :)

Comment: I only noticed now of a little problem that it seems to cause. At the bottom-left corner of my UI buttons, there are some little coloured triangles. How can i fix that? I edited my answer so you can see what they look like (I will reward you 50rep more for that as well)

Comment: This is likely a result of "Tight packing". You can disable this option on the sprite atlas and it may take up slightly more space (it should only be a few MB at most). The sprite atlas is probably rotating and fitting your sprites together, causing some overlaps. @enricortinovis

Answer (score 1):

Checkout out [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/)! It will compress your images without loosing quality.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already compressed all the images, from about 70MB total to 9MB. The problem is, as I said, that unity seems to uncompress the files when building the apk! How to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the compression for specific build targets in the import settings of images. Here you can set stuff like "max size" and compressor quality, you can tweak them a bit and see how it affects your build size.

Personally I use the following settings for android builds:
*Max size:* 2048
*Resize algo:* Mitchell
*Format:* RGBA Compressed ETC2 8 bits
*Compressor Quality:* normal

[image]

On top of that make sure you have set the Texture compression in the build settings of your application under the android build settings. Setting "Texture compression" to ETC2 (GLES 3.0) should yield the best results.

[image]